# Does PHP offer Lucene Client API like it offer Spinx client API?

Tags: php, api, lucene, client, sphinx

Does PHP offer Lucene Cient API the way it offers [Sphinx Client API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sphinx.php) ?

Considering I want to use with native PHP, not with any framework.

Comment: Maybe not an exact duplicate but ...related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010663/lucene-with-php

Answer (score 0):

not that i know of, except that there is a pecl extension that you may use to query solr.. however, you need to install solr (which offers lucene indexes/searches as a webservice through a tomcat app server): https://www.php.net/solr

other than that, i recently started using Zend_Lucene (i know you specifically say you dont want to use any framework, -and i'm not a fan of zf either-, but it seems to work ok)