# Database Table structure for search engine for my website

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to make a search engine for my website. How should I design  the table which keeps the list of indexed words.

Earlier I thought something like this:

Table: `tbl_indexedwords` has 2 columns `iw_wordid` and `iw_word`.

Table: `tbl_wordoccurrence` has 4 columns `wo_occurrenceid`, `wo_wordid`, `wo_pageid`, `wo_numberofoccurrences`.

Now, this design will not work well if the user enters more than two words in the search box. Suppose `foo bar`. Even if `foo` and `bar` both are present in the table `tbl_indexedwords` and corresponding details are in the `tbl_wordoccurrence`, my search engine script would rank the results where it sees maximum `wo_numberofoccurrences` for either `foo` or `bar`. It will not see whether `foo` and `bar` are present next to each other as  there is no column for order of occurrence of the words. I hope I am clear with what I am saying here.

Another idea could be to make the table `tbl_wordoccurrence` of 3 columns. Forget about `wo_numberofoccurences` and store each word in the page with unique `wo_occurrenceid`. Now, this would solve my problem as I know the order of occurrence of the words. if  `wo_occurrenceid` of some word is `wo_occurrenceid`+1 or `wo_occurrenceid`-1 of some other word then, these two occur side by side.

The problem with this design is that it would take up lots of space. I have lots of content for my website.  I think this approach would make it slow(not sure, though). Is there any other design that would help me? Or will I have to go with the second one? I am sure the first one is not gonna work, so discarding it.

Comment: I would suggest using `FULLTEXT` capability of your database system (if it provides) or using some ready made frameworks like **[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)**, which are mature enough to fullfill your requirement effectively, rather than re-inventing the wheel on your own.

Comment: @RumitParakhiya Does Lucene work with php? I thought Its for java!

Comment: I really don't have much idea about using Lucene with php, but [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010663/lucene-with-php) or [this link](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the contents of your website is on the database (I assume) creating a separate table would not even necessary if you are using `FULLTEXT` index. If you are using mySQL then it has such capability see the examples [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/9/3/18) and [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/477.cfm). And if you are using MSSQL it has also its own `FULLTEXT` indexing capability like the example [here](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3446891/Understanding-SQL-Server-Full-Text-Indexing.htm) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

And if you insist if having a separate table for searching then you could most likely have only one table  needed like:

```
Table  : tbl_wordsoccurrence
Fields : words_id, words 
(and if you like you can include also number_of_occurences and page_id fields)
```

In the table above you could either store one word like `programming` or phrases like `php programming`.

On the other hand if your website is `static` meaning the content is not saved on a database and therefore changes had to be made manually rather than by regular user input then that's another story.

Comment: Thanks. I was't aware about this :)