# Search for a phrase in a .txt file with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have got a HUGE file in which there are lines of data (pretty much of equal length). I would like to browse through them and find every occurance of a certain word, then take the whole line where that word occured and echo it out to the screen. Currently I am using this method:

```
$result_counter = 0;
$result_array[1] = 'No results';

$search_slug = $request->input('search_slug');
$fp = fopen(base_path('storage\app\xas.txt'), "r");

while (false !== ($line = fgets($fp))) {
    // Process $line, e.g split it into values since it is CSV.

    $exploded = explode('-', $line);
    $exploded = implode('', $exploded);
    set_time_limit(30);
    if(strpos($exploded, strtoupper($search_slug))) {
        $result_counter++;
        $result_array[$result_counter] = $exploded;
    }
}
return view('results')->with(array('results' => $result_array, 'query' => $search_slug));
fclose($fp);
```

Going line by line through a huge file just takes too long.

**You might ask - why don't you use MySQL?**

There is a huge problem with that - my file is 2.5 million lines long and might be even bigger soon. The owner of my server will ban my account if I try to update the database in one go, not to mention the fact that people are going to query large portions of it on an hourly basis. I can't afford a "no-limit" server either. I will move to MySQL as soon as it's possible, but right now I need a quick solution.

**How can I solve this problem using PHP? Is there a way to search for word occurances in a file and then grabbing those lines only?**

Comment: I'd use an actual searchable index like Lucene (or whatever the modern equivalent is). Some hints here ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010663/lucene-with-php

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thanks for the tip, I'll research it.

Comment: Maybe a system call to `grep`?

Comment: "The owner of my server will ban my account if I try to update the database in one go, not to mention the fact that people are going to query large portions of it on an hourly basis." Presumably if you are switching to a database, you should only have to update the database *once* and then *only* use the database from there on. If you properly organize and index your tables your queries should take only milliseconds to execute.

Comment: Well, I tried it on a local server on a pretty good machine with a server processor. It took 10 minutes to update 50k records. I need to create 2.5 million records or more (as soon as I get more lines in the .txt file). I am just afraid that the server owner won't be happy and might ban me. It wouldn't be that bad if I didn't share my hosting with a friend.

Comment: To update, or to insert?

Comment: @Mike Sorry, to insert.

Comment: Seems like you're probably inserting one row per query. That's extremely inefficient. Try inserting multiple values per query and it should be significantly faster.

Comment: If your "host is going to ban you", why don't you just grab yourself a VPS? It's like $8 a month for some top quality stuff. Then you can do as Mike's stated and run a DB without any fear of your hosting being removed.

Comment: @Mike so what you're saying is that I should try to insert (let's say) 100 different records per one query? I am used to inserting them one-by-one but you made a great point. I hope that the size alone won't be a problem, the .txt is about 200MB .

Comment: @Darren well I have never used a VPS, I am a bit behind, I will research VPSes to see what are the advantages. Thank you.

Comment: That's alright Peter, we all have to start somewhere! I personally use [Vultr](http://www.vultr.com), but you have a range of choices, like [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/). That way, you can simply scale your solution as your database grows! But as @Mike said again, if indexed correctly, your queries should take milliseconds. (Using a VPS allows you to be the "owner", so you circumvent any issues arising that way)

Comment: @Pe-Ter If you have enough disk space, that shouldn't be an issue. I once had to insert about 35000 rows into a database and by inserting multiple values per query I was able to reduce the execution time from something like 200 seconds to around 3 seconds if my memory serves me correctly. That's definitely the way to go.

Comment: What everyone else said: properly `indexed` tables can take milliseconds to update. I just finished updating a table with 15+ million rows in less than 10 seconds right before I came here ;x

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this `^.*yourword.*$.`

Resource: http://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html

Comment: It doesn't matter whether I use regex or strpos. This is not my problem, my problem is about speed when browsing through a file.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting, "*Search for a phrase in a .txt file with PHP*" also "*I would like to browse through them and find every occurance of a certain word,*"

Comment: I have my doubts that the bottleneck comes from looping over the file. See my comment above.